# Pyramid console script - DBSession not inserting?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a working Pyramid web app, based on the SQLAlchemy scaffold.  Within my application, I have a function that sends emails and inserts/updates tables in my database via SQLAlchemy.  On the web, I call this function via a view, i.e., a button on the web submits to a view and within the view it calls the function.

I would like to create a console script that calls this same function, but on a scheduled basis.  I'm working through the sample documentation for [setting up a Pyramid console script](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#writing-a-script).  In a perfect world I want to be able to access all of my models and functions that I'm using in my web app, but be able to use them from the console.  Through trial and error I've managed to include some basics to get something working, in that I'm able to query one of my model objects and print it to the console.  I'm even able to call the function that I want.

However, inside the function it writes a row to the database and sends out an email. When I call the function from the console, it does all the work (at least printed to the console) and sends the emails.  It prints 'INSERT' statements where it should.  But it isn't actually either executing the INSERTs or committing them, I'm not sure which.  I'm importing the DBSession from my models.py package that the rest of the pyramid app uses, but is there a trick or something I need to know?  I tried declaring a new DBSession and creating it custom to the console script but that threw some sort of "can't find a mapper" error.

In the example below, SendEmail gets called for each record; the function itself basically looks up the corresponding record, inserts a row back into the database for another model object, then sends the email.  It works great as part of the web app.  On the console side here, it prints out that it's doing everything it should be doing and sends the emails, but the database record isn't actually inserted.

Here's my console script:

```
# describe the script here

import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import logging
import optparse
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
import sys
import textwrap

import pyramid.paster
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
from pyramid.request import Request

from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError
from sqlalchemy import (
    or_,
    and_,
    not_,
    asc,
    desc,
    func
    )

from functions import SendEmail
from models import DBSession, LogSession, groupfinder

from models import MyObject

from pyramid.session import UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig

my_session_factory = UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig('itsaseekreet')

from pyramid.config import Configurator

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension


def main():
    description = """\
        Print the deployment settings for a Pyramid application.  Example:
        'show_settings deployment.ini'
        """
    usage = "usage: %prog config_uri"
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(
        usage=usage,
        description=textwrap.dedent(description)
    )
    parser.add_option(
        '-o', '--omit',
        dest='omit',
        metavar='PREFIX',
        type='string',
        action='append',
        help=("Omit settings which start with PREFIX (you can use this "
              "option multiple times)")
    )
    options, args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    if not len(args) >= 1:
        print('You must provide at least one argument')
        return 2
    config_uri = args[0]
    omit = options.omit
    if omit is None:
        omit = []

    request = Request.blank('/', base_url='http://localhost:13715/')
    env = bootstrap(config_uri, request=request)
    settings = env['registry'].settings
    pyramid.paster.setup_logging(config_uri)

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    LogSession.configure(bind=engine)
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        'itsaseekreet', callback=groupfinder)
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          root_factory='myapp.models.RootFactory',
                          session_factory=my_session_factory)
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    log.info('Starting EmailSender...')

    init_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    log.info('Current datetime (UTC): {0}'.format(str(init_time)))

    items_to_process = DBSession.query(MyObject). \
        filter(and_(MyObject.startdate <= init_time,
                    MyObject.enddate >= init_time,
                    MyObject.manual_send_only == False)).all()


    for item in items_to_process:
        log.info('{0}: runtime: {1}'.format(item.description, item.send_time))
        item_url = request.route_url('itemresponse', responseid='XXXXXX')

        rtn = SendEmail(item.id, item_url)

    env['closer']()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, another thing I'm running into but not so important right now: I have logging handlers where my log.blah goes to the database (using the LogSession I've created).  This also works fine from the web app, but is not writing to the database when I run it.  I don't know if it's the same issue, or if in my config the handlers aren't set up right for console or something.  I dunno, but the main issue above is what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

EDIT:
I poked at it some more and found [the tutorial talking about SQLAlchemy setup](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/getting_started/11-sqlalchemy/index.html) and was looking at the initializedb.py script, since that modifies the database like I want and hooks up to the models, too. I did `import transaction` and wrapping the above with

```
with transaction.manager:
    items_to_process = DBSession.query(MyObject). \
        filter(and_(MyObject.startdate <= init_time,
                    MyObject.enddate >= init_time,
                    MyObject.manual_send_only == False)).all()


    for item in items_to_process:
        log.info('{0}: runtime: {1}'.format(item.description, item.send_time))
        item_url = request.route_url('itemresponse', responseid='XXXXXX')

        rtn = SendEmail(item.id, item_url)
```

This seems to do exactly what I want, or at least actual does commit and write to the database. I'm going to have to work with it some more since I'm not exactly sure what happens if there's a DB error within the called function, if it rolls the whole thing back, if it commits part of it, or what. Within the function itself there is exception handling and and cleanup but I think it normally depends on the pyramid_tm and Zope to handle the behind the scenes stuff.

Comment: Maybe more specifically is, if I have a working pyramid web app, what do I need to do to set up a console script that has access to the same models and functions that the web app does?  I'm including and loading my development.ini successfully per the sample, and imported in my specific models object. And the database read works just fine. But do I need additional configuration or includes or something?

Comment: So... is there still a question to be answered here?

Comment: It'll rollback the whole thing back in case of error. If you want to do it in parts read about savepoints in `transaction` package documentaion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you never commit your changes.

```
DBSession.commit()
```

call it before your `closer` function. It should work according to how you use `DBSession`.

Comment: Even if my main Pyramid .models package (that includes the MyObject I'm working with) uses ZopeTransactionExtension?  I thought ZTE automatically handled committing via DBSession.flush() if I needed to, and I thought I've run into SQLAlchemy problems in the past trying to explicitly commit. Besides, the actual database transactions doing the updates/inserts are within the "SendEmail()" function that is being called by the console app. Or is there something else I need to do to get the same db functionality I have in my we app but in the console script?

Comment: I can't be sure (I don't know how you define `DBSession`), but if you use ZTE, you should use `transaction` package to commit.

Comment: @PeterTirrell Yes, even if you use ZopeTransactionExtension. No, ZTE won't automatically commit any changes for you, it just joins sqlalchemy session to zope transaction. You probably use `pyramid_tm` to automatically commit changes in your web app, but it won't be executed in your script.

Comment: Ah, interesting to know then.  I'll try committing then tonight; or, since yes, I think I am using pyramid_tm in my web app - is there a way to integrate that with my script? It would be nice to be have the two as similar as possibly I would think.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @PeterTirrell I don't think there is a good way to do that. `pyramid_tm` is really just a function that calls your view and handles transaction around. It would keep your code simpler to use `transaction` directly, also it is much easier. `pyramid_tm` was specifically designed to handle requests in pyramid apps and not for scripts.

Comment: I poked at it some more and found [the tutorial talking about SQLAlchemy setup](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/getting_started/11-sqlalchemy/index.html) and was looking at the initializedb.py script, since that modifies the database like I want and hooks up to the models, too. My comment is too long so I'm going to edit my original question with my observation.